# Extract variable names from the string expression using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string, formula, algebra

I have a algebraic expression in in string. I want to extract the variable names from the expression. The variable names should follow python variable naming rules. (should be combination of letter or numbers, should not start with a number, can have underscore etc)

example:

```
formula = 'value1 * 5 + value_2 /4'
```

it should give a result of `['value1', 'value_2']`

Comment: ([a-zA-Z])\w+
this is giving me the best match so far. but ignoring some of the variable

Comment: for what purpose may i ask?

Comment: ｈｏｍｅｗｏｒｋ？post you code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of a regular expression - if possible - I'd use the `ast` module which parses Python's code itself. That means you're not having to worry about string literals/other stuff and if the parsing fails, you'll get an error which means it's a not complete or an invalid statement:

```
import ast

formula = 'value1 * 5 + value_2 /4'
names = [
    node.id for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(formula)) 
    if isinstance(node, ast.Name)
]
# ['value1', 'value_2']
```